# i want not to use the variable in a t() drupal message

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

```
$loglink = l("blabla", 'admin/config/blabla');
drupal_set_message(t("You have to complete the fields in $loglink first."), 'error');
```

How can I write that message, but not to use the variable `$loglink` in the t(). Is there away to do it with array?

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want to use it, then don't use it.

Comment: i want all the other sentence be in the t().. :/

Comment: What's preventing you from deleting the word `$loglink` from the sentence?

Comment: i want to put a link in this sentence but to get out the variable to not be t()

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put what you are assigning to the variable in place of the variable?

```
drupal_set_message(t("You have to complete the fields in " . l("blabla", 'admin/config/blabla') . " first."), 'error');
```

Or, using **placeholders**:

```
drupal_set_message(t("You have to complete the fields in !link first.", array('!link' => l("blabla", 'admin/config/blabla'), 'error');
```

Since you are using **t()** then why don't you also run your link text through **t()**? And not mix single and double quotes:

```
l(t('blabla'), 'admin/config/blabla')
```

By the way you'll notice I used a ! for the beginning of the placeholder, these are available:

**!** !variable, which means that the text will be inserted as it is.

**@** @variable, which means that the text should be run through check_plain().

**%** %variable, which means that the text should run through check_plain()  and also highlight with theme_placeholder() which will show up as emphasized.

Anyway I think you should do this:

```
drupal_set_message(t('You have to complete the fields in !link first.', array('!link' => l(t('blabla'), 'admin/config/blabla'), 'error');
```

Comment: you lost a ")" in drupal_set_message(t("You have to complete the fields in !link first.", array('!link' => l("blabla", 'admin/config/blabla'), 'error');
and it not working :'( and this is what i am searching for

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to have links in translatable content is

```
t('Have a look at the <a href="@drupal-handbook">Drupal Handbooks</a>.',
  array(
    '@drupal-handbook' => 'http://drupal.org/handbooks',
  )
)
```

See [Dynamic or static links and HTML in translatable strings](https://www.drupal.org/node/322774).

Comment: could you help me with my example with dat drupal_set_message(,error)??